# Does $\sum_{j=1,j\neq k}^n\frac{z_k}{z_k-z_j}=\sum_{j=1,j\neq m}^n\frac{z_m}{z_m-z_j}$ implies the $(z_j)_{j=1,...,n}$ are the nth roots of $z_1^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, symmetric-polynomials, roots-of-unity

Let $(z_1,\ldots z_n)\subseteq \mathbb{C}.$
Does
$$
    \sum_{j=1\,,\,j\neq k}^n \frac{z_k}{z_k-z_j}=\sum_{j=1\,,\,j\neq k'}^n \frac{z_{k'}}{z_{k'}-z_j}
$$ for all $k,k'\in\{1,...,n\}\,$, implies that the $(z_j)_{j=1,...,n}$ are the n-th roots of $z:=z_1^n$ ?

For example,

- for $n=2$, we can verify that $z_1=-z_2$ .
- For $n=3$, we can also verify that the $(z_j)_{j=1,2,3}$ can be obtained from $z_k\,,$  by a multiplication with $-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$
- The same goes for $n=4$, but with multiplication by $i$...

How can we prove it for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: What is the difference between the right and left sides of the equation with summations? Shouldn't it be like $j \ne k, k\ne k'$ or something like that?

Comment: @LinconRibeiro . For example, for $n=3$, $$\frac{z_1}{z_1-z_2}+\frac{z_1}{z_1-z_3}=\frac{z_2}{z_2-z_1}+\frac{z_2}{z_2-z_3}=\frac{z_3}{z_3-z_1}+\frac{z_3}{z_3-z_2}$$

Comment: The condition on the sum is extremely symmetric, so it brought to my mind Galois theory, or the fundamental theorem of symmetric rational functions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618851/symmetric-rational-function-is-a-rational-function-in-the-elementary-symmetric-p (the condition says that the sum is in the subfield fixed by every transposition/swap $z_k \leftrightarrow z_{k'}$; transpositions generate the whole symmetric group $S_n$). Perhaps looking around in that subject, someone has already worked on a general method or questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is affirmative. I'm using a bit of calculus here.

Let $f(z):=\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)$. Then $f'(z)/f(z)=\sum_{j=1}^n 1/(z-z_j)$ and, for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, $$\sum_{j\neq k}\frac{z_k}{z_k-z_j}=z_k\lim_{z\to z_k}\left(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}-\frac1{z-z_k}\right)\underset{\text{L'Hôpital}}{\phantom{\big[}=\phantom{\big]}}\frac{z_kf''(z_k)}{2f'(z_k)}.$$

We're given that this quantity doesn't depend on $k$. Then $g(z_k)/f'(z_k)=\lambda$ doesn't depend on $k$ as well, where $g(z):=zf''(z)-(n-1)f'(z)$ has degree less than $n-1$.

Thus, $g(z_k)-\lambda f'(z_k)=0$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, which implies $g(z)=\lambda f'(z)$ identically. This is impossible if $\lambda\neq 0$ (the degrees don't match), hence $zf''(z)=(n-1)f'(z)$.

Now solve this ODE...